# Python typing: Retrieve required keys from TypedDict definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typing, code-inspection

In Python3.10, I have a `typing.TypedDict` definition and want to programmatically retrieve which keys are required. How can I inspect the type definition in order to get the required keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking [PEP-655](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0655/) into account, there are different scenarios: The whole `TypedDict` could have `total=False` or `total=True`, and individual fields could be marked as either `Required` or `NotRequired`. And there could also be [the edge case](https://bugs.python.org/issue38834) where a `TypedDict` is inheriting from another, and one of them has `total=False` and the other one has `total=True`. In order to handle this edge case, Python introduced the `__required_keys__` attribute on the `TypedDict`. This is what we have to look at:

```py
from typing import Any, _TypedDictMeta


def required_keys(type_: _TypedDictMeta) -> frozenset[str]:
    return type_.__required_keys__
```